# Write $(b+d)(a'+b'+c)$ in both minimal and canonical sum of products form

Tags: boolean-algebra

> Write the following expression in both minimal and canonical sum of products form
>
> $$(b+d)(a'+b'+c).$$

I made the truth tables for both and got the following:

$$a'b'c'd + a'b'cd + a'bcd + abcd' + ab'c'd + ab'cd + abcd.$$

I also tried distributing it and got:

$$a'b + bb' + bc + a'd + b'd + cd
= a'(b+d) + c(b+d) + b'd$$

Am I doing this right so far?
Also what do I do next?

Comment: You distributed the terms correctly.  You may want to check out the Wikipedia article on Karnaugh maps at   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map.  They provide a nice visual way of deciding if you can get less terms for your sum.